# need some help getting the buttons working on my assignment been trying for 4 hours

Tags: html

the main problem im having is that the color buttons and the grow and the shrink buttons are not currently working. ive fixed several things that would have effected them but they still dont want to work for me. the only page i havent found an error on so far was the css page and the assignment did say that there would be at least one error on each page but im not sure where to start.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Boo The Dog</title>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Linking CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <!-- Linking jQuery -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Linking Google Fonts -->
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Roboto+Slab|Yellowtail' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron bg-primary text-center">
                <h1>Boo The Dog Fan Page!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">Instructions</div>
                        <div class="panel-body text-center">
                            <h4>Oh no! Someone has vandalized our Boo 'The Cutest Dog In The World' fanpage!</h4>
                            <h4>There are a bunch of errors on this page!</h4>
                            <h4>Try your best to find them all!</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">About Boo</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            Boo the dog belongs to a San Francisco-based Facebook employee who created a Facebook page for the dog with a statement "My name is Boo. I am a dog. Life is good." He became popular in October 2010 after singer Ke$ha sent a tweet that she had a new boyfriend, linking to the page.
                            Chronicle Books, noticing that Boo had 5 million Facebook fans at the time, approached the owner to write a picture book. In August 2011, Boo: The Life of the World's Cutest Dog, written by his owner under pen name J.H. Lee, was published. The book was eventually published in ten languages. A second book followed, Boo: Little Dog in the Big City, as well as a calendar and plans for a cut-out book and additional children's books. He also has his own stuffed animal for kids. His merchandise includes a Gund stuffed animal.
                            Boo was appointed a spokesdog for Virgin America airline, which featured photos of him in an airplane along with advice for people traveling with pets. In April 2012, Boo was the subject of a death hoax after #RIPBOO appeared on Facebook. Tweets followed as Gizmodo writer Sam Biddle tweeted Boo had died. It was later confirmed by The Chronicle Book staff that Boo was alive and well. In July 2012, Boo was named the Official Pet Liaison of Virgin America.
                            Read more at: <a href="">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo_(dog)</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="well text-center">
                        <div>
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-04/21/16/enhanced/webdr05/enhanced-31550-1429646952-7.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="factButton">Random Boo Fact</button>
                    <div class="well text-center">
                        <div>
                            <p id="factText">Click the button for a random Boo fact!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">List Of Boo's Favorite Things</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ol>
                                <li>Dressing Up</li>
                                <li>Eating Grass</li>
                                <li>Sleeping</li>
                                <li>Swimming</li>
                                <li>Hiking</li>
                            </ol>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br><br><br><br>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
                    <button class="btn" id="textGreen">Orange</button>
                    <button class="btn" id="textOrange">Pink</button>
                    <button class="btn" id="textPink">Green</button>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="well text-center">
                        <p id="funText">Boo Rules!</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <button class="btn" id="boxGrow">Grow</button>
                    <button class="btn" id="boxShrink">Shrink</button>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="well text-center">
                        <img id="box" src="http://petradioshow.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/jiff1.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="errors.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```js
$("#factButton").on("click", function() {
    var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * booFacts.length));
    $("#factText").text(booFacts[number])
})

var booFacts = ["Boo is a pomeranian, Boo's best friend is another pomeranian named Buddy, Boo the Pomeranian was born on March 16, making him a Pisces, Boo's favourite food is grass, Boo has released two books" ]

$("#textPink").on("click", function() {
    $("#funText").css("color", "pink")
})

$("#textOrange").on("click", function() {
    $("#funText").css("color", "orange")
})

$("#textGreen").on("click", function() {
    $("#funText").css("color", "green" )
})

$("#boxGrow").on("click", function() {
    $("#box").animate({height:"+=35px", 
        width:"+=35px"}, "fast");
})

$("#boxShrink").on("click", function() {
    $("#box").animate({height:"-=35px", width:"-=35px"}, "fast");
})
```

CSS:

```css
.jumbotron {
    background-color: #428bca
}

.jumbotron h1 {
    color:white;
}

p, h1, h4 {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

#funText {
    color: black;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

#box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the error message

Comment: im not sure how would i find out the error message?

Comment: inspect > console > copy and paste the red bit into your edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry no one helped you, your issue was actually quite simple to solve and as you get better these things will become second nature. You where on the right track, here are your issues:

1. When using jQuery you need to tell it when you want it to
   initialize. [jQuery Document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)
2. Arrays should be comma separated and encapsulated. [JS Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

Im still not sure what the `errors.js` does.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Boo The Dog</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Linking CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <!-- Linking jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Linking Google Fonts -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Roboto+Slab|Yellowtail' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <style>
        .jumbotron {
            background-color: #428bca
        }

        .jumbotron h1 {
            color: white;
        }

        p, h1, h4 {
            font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
        }

        #funText {
            color: black;
            font-size: 24px;
            font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
        }

        #box {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $("#factButton").on("click", function () {
                var number = Math.floor((Math.random() * booFacts.length));
                $("#factText").text(booFacts[number])
            });

            var booFacts = ["Boo is a pomeranian", "Boo's best friend is another pomeranian named Buddy", "Boo the Pomeranian was born on March 16, making him a Pisces", "Boo's favourite food is grass", "Boo has released two books"];

            $("#textPink").on("click", function () {
                $("#funText").css("color", "pink")
            });

            $("#textOrange").on("click", function () {
                $("#funText").css("color", "orange")
            });

            $("#textGreen").on("click", function () {
                $("#funText").css("color", "green")
            });

            $("#boxGrow").on("click", function () {
                $("#box").animate({
                    height: "+=35px",
                    width: "+=35px"
                }, "fast");
            });

            $("#boxShrink").on("click", function () {
                $("#box").animate({height: "-=35px", width: "-=35px"}, "fast");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron bg-primary text-center">
        <h1>Boo The Dog Fan Page!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">Instructions</div>
                <div class="panel-body text-center">
                    <h4>Oh no! Someone has vandalized our Boo 'The Cutest Dog In The World' fanpage!</h4>
                    <h4>There are a bunch of errors on this page!</h4>
                    <h4>Try your best to find them all!</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">About Boo</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>
                        Boo the dog belongs to a San Francisco-based Facebook employee who created a Facebook page for
                        the dog with a statement "My name is Boo. I am a dog. Life is good." He became popular in
                        October 2010 after singer Ke$ha sent a tweet that she had a new boyfriend, linking to the page.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Chronicle Books, noticing that Boo had 5 million Facebook fans at the time, approached the owner
                        to write a picture book. In August 2011, Boo: The Life of the World's Cutest Dog, written by his
                        owner under pen name J.H. Lee, was published. The book was eventually published in ten
                        languages. A second book followed, Boo: Little Dog in the Big City, as well as a calendar and
                        plans for a cut-out book and additional children's books. He also has his own stuffed animal for
                        kids. His merchandise includes a Gund stuffed animal.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Boo was appointed a spokesdog for Virgin America airline, which featured photos of him in an
                        airplane along with advice for people traveling with pets. In April 2012, Boo was the subject of
                        a death hoax after #RIPBOO appeared on Facebook. Tweets followed as Gizmodo writer Sam Biddle
                        tweeted Boo had died. It was later confirmed by The Chronicle Book staff that Boo was alive and
                        well. In July 2012, Boo was named the Official Pet Liaison of Virgin America.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Read more at:
                        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo_(dog)" target="_blank" title="Boo Wiki Info">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo_(dog)</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="well text-center">
                <div>
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2015-04/21/16/enhanced/webdr05/enhanced-31550-1429646952-7.jpg" alt="Boo grow and shrink">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="factButton">Random Boo Fact</button>
            <div class="well text-center">
                <div>
                    <p id="factText">Click the button for a random Boo fact!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">List Of Boo's Favorite Things</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ol>
                        <li>Dressing Up</li>
                        <li>Eating Grass</li>
                        <li>Sleeping</li>
                        <li>Swimming</li>
                        <li>Hiking</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
            <button class="btn" id="textGreen">Orange</button>
            <button class="btn" id="textOrange">Pink</button>
            <button class="btn" id="textPink">Green</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="well text-center">
                <p id="funText">Boo Rules!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn" id="boxGrow">Grow</button>
            <button class="btn" id="boxShrink">Shrink</button>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="well text-center">
                <img id="box" src="http://petradioshow.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/jiff1.jpg" alt="Boo the dog">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="errors.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```